# Create MyItem class to be categorized by type

Tags: c#, attributes

I have the following code, when I declare `MyItem`, it will be automatically added into `Roster`.

```
public class MyItem
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> Roster;

    public static bool addToRoster(MyItem item)
    {
        if (Roster.ContainsKey(item.code))
            return false;

        Roster.Add(item.code, item.description);

        return true;
    }

    public string code { get; protected set; }
    public string description { get; protected set; }

    public MyItem(string _code, string _desc)
    {
        code = _code;
        description = _desc;
        addToRoster(this);
    }
}
```

So when I use it like below, `Roster` dictionary will contain 2 values:

```
MyItem itema = new MyItem("code1", "desc1");
MyItem itemb = new MyItem("code2", "desc2");
MyItem itemc = new MyItem("code1", "desc1");
```

So far so good. Now I may have multiple Rosters, based on different type. For example, I may have a `Subject`, a `Room` and a `Building`. I don't want to declare multiple classes derived from `MyItem` class, that will be too many. Of course I can add a property

```
string RosterType { get; set; }
```

in `MyItem` class, but that will make bunch of data redundancy.

I am thinking maybe I can use attribute, but it seems attribute cannot be used on object.

I am trying to find something like this

```
[RosterType("Room")]
MyItem item1("WJ203", "Room WJ203");

[RosterType("Subject")]
MyItem item2("MATH01", "Basic Math");
```

and, change the Roster to be

```
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Rosters;
```

Then I can add the items into different rosters based on different `RosterType`. But, it seems I cannot set attribute on object.

What should I do to archive my goal? Any good thought?

Let me add some details

The data I received is like:

```
{
    result: [ 
    {
        "propA": { "code":"XXX", "desc":"XXX" },
        "propB": { "code":"XXX", "desc":"XXX" },
        "propC": { "code":"XXX", "desc":"XXX" }
    },
    {
        "propA": { "code":"XXX", "desc":"XXX" },
        "propB": { "code":"XXX", "desc":"XXX" },
        "propC": { "code":"XXX", "desc":"XXX" }
    },
    {
        "propA": { "code":"XXX", "desc":"XXX" },
        "propB": { "code":"XXX", "desc":"XXX" },
        "propC": { "code":"XXX", "desc":"XXX" }
    }]
}
```

There are many different type of result, and most of them are combination of different type of props. all the props are in cod - desc format. I know it is a poor design, but nothing I can do from my side. I need to save the result into different tables, with just code; and also need to save all the code into different code tables. All these need to be done during desearlization. so I am hopping to do this in MyItem class. The categorize procedure maybe happen in OnDesearlization. So for the result part, I can easily customize my class based on different type of result.

Comment: I would question your design, in so far that a room might not have anything to do with a subject or a building. I would rather guess that a building has rooms, and then in rooms certain courses can be held. I don't believe that one room can be in different buildings, but you might have several subjects that take place in different rooms that are then parts of some buildings. So, if I were you I would go back to the drawingboard

Comment: i might did not give you a good example on roster, but that's not the point. I received huge amount of data, which most of the things are in a code - desc format. i need to save code part only, but update my roster table accordingly.

Comment: From the explanation you have given, you seem to get more info (since you know what type of data you are dealing with). If the info you have given is insufficient, then feel free to add some sample data and what your eventual output would be. I think it's a nice question you have posted, I am only asking if you could take a step back and evaluate your workflow again, maybe you got stuck on an initial idea of implementation and overlooked another one.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: Maybe you need a factory method instead, which returns you with an `IRosterItem`, that has a specific implementation based on the input given?

Comment: The point is, how to assign the different 'category' to a class, but based on the object? factory vs static member, it is just different implementations.
If you create 1 implementation based on input, that means input must contains the 'category' information, which is not possible. if you create multiple implementation, that is not what I want.

Comment: I already have a walk-around, with just 1 implementation. Bear with me some time and I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is, set the attribute to properties. Have a ResultBase class, which will go over the attributes, and if a Roster Item found, deal with it. So Once all this are done, I just need to declare my different Results with no extra coding...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Reflection;

namespace RosterNS
{
    using IRoster = IDictionary<string, string>;

    [DataContract]
    public class RosterItem
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string code { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rosters
    {
        static private Dictionary<string, IRoster> rosters = new Dictionary<string, IRoster>();
        public static IRoster RegisterRoster(string category)
        {
            IRoster roster;

            if (!rosters.TryGetValue(category, out roster))
            {
                roster = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                rosters.Add(category, roster);
            }

            return roster;
        }
#if DEBUG
        public static void ListRosters()
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, IRoster> kvp in rosters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Category:{0}", kvp.Key.ToString());
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> skvp in kvp.Value)
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0:20}==>{1}", skvp.Key, skvp.Value);
            }
        }
#endif
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class RosterCategoryAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private IRoster roster;
        public string Category { get; protected set; }

        public RosterCategoryAttribute(string category)
        {
            Category = category;
            roster = Rosters.RegisterRoster(category);
        }

        public void addToRoster(RosterItem item)
        {
            if (item != null && !roster.ContainsKey(item.code))
                roster.Add(item.code, item.description);
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class RosterResult
    {
        //The only implementation that save the RosterItem into categorized Roster
        [OnDeserialized]
        public void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext sc)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
            {
                RosterCategoryAttribute attr = info.GetCustomAttribute<RosterCategoryAttribute>();
                if (attr != null)
                    attr.addToRoster(info.GetValue(this) as RosterItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, I need to declare my Result like so

```
namespace MyResult
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ResultType1 : RosterResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        [RosterCategory("Location")]
        public RosterItem location { get; protected set; }

        [DataMember]
        [RosterCategory("Status")]
        public RosterItem status { get; protected set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ResultType2 : RosterResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        [RosterCategory("Location")]
        public RosterItem location { get; protected set; }

        [DataMember]
        [RosterCategory("Equipment")]
        public RosterItem equipment { get; protected set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; protected set; }
    }
}
```

So after bunch of deserialization, the Roster will be filled up with unique code-spec pair, based on different categories.